# OpenGL vs DirectX, memory used when loading shaders

Tags: c++, opengl, directx-11

I have an application which has many different shaders, and has both an OpenGL and DirectX 11 implementation. Other than language differences (between GLSL and HLSL), the shaders are identical on both platforms. In DirectX, the shaders are compiled offline using `fxc` (with the `/Fh` option), and compiled into the executable. In OpenGL, the text of the shader is embedded into the executable, and is compiled at runtime. It then will be saved as binary with `glGetProgramBinary` (if the platform is capable, which it is on the test case I have), and reloaded on subsequent runs with `glProgramBinary`.

I have noticed that in OpenGL, the total memory reported used by my application (reported in procexp) grows by an average of 49kb per call `glProgramBinary`. The increase seems to be not directly related to the size of the program's binary. Some increase memory roughly the size of the binary, where as some raise it by many times the size. Also, the binary sizes seem quite large, being ~12kb even for the simplest programs.

Conversely, in DirectX 11, the equivalent calls to `ID3D11Device::CreateVertexShader` and `ID3D11Device::CreatePixelShader` do increase the reported memory usage, but only by an average of 6kb per pair (again, the increase seems not directly proportional to the size of the binary). Also, the shader binary blobs compiled offline seem to be drastically smaller, with the smallest being less than 2kb.

Is there some way to reduce the amount of memory associated with shaders in OpenGL, such that it's more inline with the memory usage in DirectX? Or, is this a reporting problem (DirectX is actually using the memory, but it doesn't show up in the process' count)?

(Platform is NVidia 373.34, on Windows 10).

Comment: For DirectX, you can use FXC compiler options  ``/Qstrip_reflect`` and ``/Qstrip_debug`` to minimize the size of shader blobs, but there's not much you can do to control how much memory the driver decide to use when it compiles them from IR to the hardware's microcode.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn - yes, already using those for D3D (in addition to /O3).

Comment: To note that with dx11, the shader does not really turn into final microcode before usage. And a single instance of I*Shader can derive in the driver to several recompilation depending on the use case later. A compiler is also a piece of code that can use a fair amount of memory, especially for the GL case, and it is not impossible that the driver group memory allocation to limit interaction with the OS. Shaders also are stored finally in gpu memory that will not show in the process explorer.

Comment: I have to ask: does it matter? 49 kilobytes is 0.000046 of a gigabyte. You're going to have to load thousands of shader binary programs before there's a detectable change in program execution speed on any Windows 10 PC.
Please note I'm all in favour of learning how stuff works and figuring out odd behaviour of this kind. Just be aware of why you're doing it.

Comment: It's not about execution speed, it's about memory (the shaders load at an acceptable speed on both). After loading 1000 shaders, taking 40k extra memory per shader, that's 40MB, which is not an insignificant amount of memory. On 32-bit operating systems, it's literally 1% of your total possible memory usage, just for shaders.